# Put default image in slideshow while there's no picture displayed using Codeigniter and Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

I am having trouble on my code. It won't show the default image. Here's my code

```
<div id="SS" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#SS" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#SS" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#SS" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php
        $no=1;
        $default=$this->db->get_where("penyaluran", array("status" => "1"))->result();
        foreach ($default as $pict)
        {                           
        if ($pict->status > "0")
        {
        $g=$pict->foto_dokumentasi;
        $n=$pict->nama_penyaluran;
        }
        else
        {
        $g='image.jpg';
        $n='';
        }

        if ($no == 1)
        {
        $status = 'active';
        }
        else
        {
        $status = "";
        }?>
        <div class="carousel-item <?php echo $status; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$g); ?>" alt="" style="max-height: 300px; width: 1200px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3><?php echo $n; ?></h3> 
        </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#SS" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#SS" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark"></span>
        </a>
        <?php
        $no++;
        } ?>
        </div>
```

P.S 1 is displayed while 0 is not displayed. I plan to display the default image while all pictures are not displayed.

Comment: did it display the non-default image?

Comment: no, it's just blank

Comment: but when i display one or two picts from my table, they pop out on the slideshow